# flamingo and underachiever

Tags: synonyms

Today (2022.05.26), Windows PC shows a desktop picture of flamingos.

And it has a caption "It's a bird species that sounds like an underachiever."

But I couldn't get a synonym of underachiever sounds like "flamingo."

Is there some synonym, or the caption refers to the "lesser" part of the lesser flamingo?

Comment: my interpretation is that this does refer to the "lesser" part of the specific name.  Is the picture a picture of *lesser* flamingos

Comment: The picture is here. I hope you can view it placed on the DropBox site  https://www.dropbox.com/s/52haadkxoejfihx/windows2022_05_26.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very likely refers to the "lesser" part of the lesser flamingo.  Lesser can refer to size being smaller, as it does for flamingos, but it can also refer to the significance being smaller.  Some common examples are a "lesser evil" or a "lesser charge", which refer to things that are less significant than their alternatives. A "lesser flamingo" could be interpreted as a flamingo that isn't as important as a regular flamingo, hence the joke that they are underachievers.